# Sardinas–Patterson algorithm terminates

Tags: algorithm

I read about the Sardinas–Patterson algorithm in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sardinas%E2%80%93Patterson_algorithm) and they have left some unanswered questions.

for example it is said that the algorithm terminates after O(n) iterations because there are only n dangling suffixes possible.  but the algorithm creates sets of dangling suffixes. and there are 2^n of these.

could someone please explain what am I missing and why does this algorithm terminates after O(n) iterations?

Comment: No, it doesn't create any groups. At each step it creates some suffixes and adds them to the set of suffixes accumulated so far.

Comment: the wikipedia page says: Otherwise, once a set 
Si equals a previously encountered set 
Sj with j<i, then the algorithm would enter in principle an endless loop. Instead of continuing endlessly. that means it does create sets of suffixes

Comment: if you say it does not create any sets than what's the stopping condition

Comment: The stopping condition is: either no new suffixes are found at some step (the answer is Yes) or one of the suffixes equals an existing *code word* (the answer is No).

Comment: It creates one particular set of suffixes. It can only contain suffixes that are suffixes of the input code words. Each code word s has length(s) different suffixes. Thus the total length of suffixes it can create is a polynomial on the total length of the input code.